# Import FBX Vertex And Index Buffer To DirectX 11

Tags: graphics, import, directx, fbx

Ok, I'm still trying to figure out how to correctly import FBX vertex and index buffer into DirectX 11. I wrote a controller for doing that and passing the vertex and index buffer to the DX11 renderer, the output should look like a cube but it is not, I only see triangles that don't make sense.

The code is shown below. I did multiply the Z values by -1, though.

What do I need to modify to get the render right?

```
#pragma once

#include "Array.h"
#include "Vector.h"
#include "fbxsdk.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include "constants.h"

class FbxController
{
public:
    FbxController();
   ~FbxController();


    void Import(const char* lFilename)
   {
        lImporter = FbxImporter::Create(lSdkManager, "");
        bool lImportStatus = lImporter->Initialize(lFilename, -1, lSdkManager->GetIOSettings());

        if (!lImportStatus) {
            printf("Call to FbxImporter::Initialize() failed.\n");
            printf("Error returned: %s\n\n", lImporter->GetStatus().GetErrorString());
            exit(-1);
        }

    lScene = FbxScene::Create(lSdkManager, "myScene");
    lImporter->Import(lScene);
    FbxNode* lRootNode = lScene->GetRootNode();
    int childCount = lRootNode->GetChildCount();
    FbxNode *node1 = lRootNode->GetChild(0);
    const char* nodeName1 = node1->GetName();
    fbxsdk::FbxMesh *mesh = node1->GetMesh();
    int cpCount1 = mesh->GetControlPointsCount();
    fbxsdk::FbxVector4 *controlPoints = mesh->GetControlPoints();
    for (int i = 0; i < cpCount1; i++)
    {
        fbxsdk::FbxVector4 cpitem = controlPoints[i];
        printf("%d, %d, %d, %d", cpitem[0], cpitem[1], cpitem[2], cpitem[3] );
        VERTEXPOSCOLOR vpc;
        vpc.Color.x = 0.5f;
        vpc.Color.y = 0.5f;
        vpc.Color.z = 0.5f;
        vpc.Position.x = cpitem[0];
        vpc.Position.y = cpitem[1];
        vpc.Position.z = cpitem[2] * -1.0f;
        m_vertices.add(vpc);
    }
    int pvCount = mesh->GetPolygonVertexCount();
    int polyCount = mesh->GetPolygonCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < polyCount; i++)
    {
        int polyItemSize = mesh->GetPolygonSize(i);
        assert(polyItemSize == 3);
        for (int j = 0; j < polyItemSize; j++)
        {
            int cpIndex = mesh->GetPolygonVertex(i, j);
            m_indices.add(cpIndex);
            float x = controlPoints[cpIndex].mData[0];
            float y = controlPoints[cpIndex].mData[1];
            float z = controlPoints[cpIndex].mData[2];
        }
    }
    fbxsdk::FbxMesh *mesh2;
    bool isT = mesh->IsTriangleMesh();
    FbxNode *node2 = lRootNode->GetChild(1);
    FbxNode *node3 = lRootNode->GetChild(2);
    //lImporter->Destroy();
}

Array<VERTEXPOSCOLOR> GetVertexPosColors()
{
    return m_vertices;
}

Array<unsigned int> getIndexBuffer()
{
    return m_indices;
}

protected:
    FbxManager *lSdkManager;
    FbxIOSettings *ios;
    FbxImporter *lImporter;
    bool lImportStatu;
    FbxScene *lScene;


private:
    Array<VERTEXPOSCOLOR> m_vertices;
    Array<unsigned int> m_indices;
};
```

Comment: The Autodesk FBX SDK is a complex beast, so this is challenging to do robustly. You might want to look at a fully working example like the [Samples Content Exporter](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=226208) or try a simpler case of exporting to something like Wavefront OBJ and importing with that--see [DirectXMesh](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=324981)'s ``meshconvert`` tool.

Comment: That's a good link, I'll definitely clone the github project and wrap some of the classes in there. I thought it was that trivial but... Also I did write a parser for the wavefront obj format, that still is a work in progress.

Comment: Parser code for WaveFront OBJ can be found in the ``meshconvert`` source.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some problems in your index buffer creation.
You simply gives an index for each vertex, and index buffer not working that way.
let me know if you solve this.